# Google Maps Android Marker Clustering with markers that get their coordinates from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use Google Maps Android Marker Clustering with markers that take Firestore coordinates.

MapsActivity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityMapsBinding binding;
    private ClusterManager<MyClusterItem> clusterManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        setUpClusterer(mMap);


        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        // SET CAMERA
        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(10.0f);
        mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20.0f);
        LatLngBounds ticinoBounds = new LatLngBounds(
                new LatLng(45.805825566907345, 8.769484272440344), // SW bounds
                new LatLng(46.16610788443759, 9.097742851389778)  // NE bounds
        );
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ticinoBounds.getCenter(), 10));
        mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(ticinoBounds);

        //INFO WINDOW

        CustomInfoWindowAdapter adapter = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MapsActivity.this);
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);

        //MARKER
        final IconGenerator tc = new IconGenerator(this);
        tc.setTextAppearance(R.style.iconGenText); // TIPO E COLORE CARATTERI
        tc.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_GREEN); // BACKGROUND

        db.collection("Places").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        if (document != null) {

                            GeoPoint geoPoint = document.getGeoPoint("geo");
                            LatLng location = new LatLng(geoPoint.getLatitude(), geoPoint.getLongitude());
                            String name = document.getString("name");
                            String descVia = document.getString("descVia");
                            String descTel = document.getString("descTel");

                            Bitmap bmp = tc.makeIcon("CHF/EUR: " + document.get("CHFEUR") + "\r\n" + "EUR/CHF: " + document.get("EURCHF"));

                            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(location)
                                    .title(name)
                                    .snippet(descVia + "\r\n" + descTel )
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
                            marker.showInfoWindow();

                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
                }
            }
        });
    }



    private void setUpClusterer(GoogleMap mMap) {


        // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
        // (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)
        clusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyClusterItem>(this, mMap);

        // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
        // manager.
        this.mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager);
        this.mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager);

        // Add cluster items (markers) to the cluster manager.
        addItems();
    }


    private void addItems() {

        // Set some lat/lng coordinates to start with.
        double lat = 45.97785520814739;
        double lng = 8.962509249084082;

        // Add ten cluster items in close proximity, for purposes of this example.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            double offset = i / 300d;
            lat = lat + offset;
            lng = lng + offset;
            MyClusterItem offsetItem = new MyClusterItem(lat, lng, "Title " + i, "Snippet " + i);

            clusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
        }
    }


}
```

addItem is an example and it works.

MyClusterTem:

```
public class MyClusterItem implements ClusterItem {
    private final LatLng position;
    private final String title;
    private final String snippet;

    public MyClusterItem(double lat, double lng, String title, String snippet) {
        position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        this.title = title;
        this.snippet = snippet;
    }


    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSnippet() {
        return snippet;
    }
}
```

I need to figure out how to integrate the same system as the example with my markers.

Thanks for help.

[image]

This is the result..

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I have no errors but I want to use Clustering with green markers.
The red markers you see are an example and it works, but I don't understand how to integrate the cluster with my markers which take the coordinates from the database.